# how can i use RGBDSlam with image

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i have a sequence of image with the format bmp(or png), they are rgb and depth image,there is no bagfiles. how can i use RGBDSlam with those dataset. thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214304/how-can-i-use-rgbdslam-with-image/) by [fdp0525](https://answers.ros.org/users/23298/fdp0525/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After you brings up RGBDSLAM by using Kinect or other RGBD sensors, you can use `rqt` to check what are the input topics of RGB and depth image for RGBDSLAM.

Let's say the topic names are /rgb_image and /depth_image, then you need to publish images in your dataset to /rgb_image and /depth_image. You can do it by reading the images from OpenCV and publish it to topics. (You might need this [ref](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages).)

Due to some problem I cannot indicate the precise topic name. But I think you can find out by yourself.

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2015-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1